# Edit vbproj file in pre-build event

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a project in a solution (that has many other projects) that I'd like to setup a "pre-build event" for that will edit the vbproj file and then build the project

Is there any tools or code available currently to accomplish that? I can't find any resources to point me in the right direction

Comment: Which particular property / setting?

Comment: <ItemGroup><EmbeddedResource>

Comment: On vcprojects is<Configurations>
  <Configuration
   Name="Release|Win32"
   OutputDirectory="..\stage\bin"
   IntermediateDirectory="Release"
   ConfigurationType="2"
   CharacterSet="1"
   >
   <Tool
    Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
    CommandLine="&quot;C:\kill peripherals.bat&quot;"
   />

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's anything out there that does this already, but below is some code that may do the job for you (with a bit of tweaking):

```
Engine eng = new Engine();            
Project proj = new Project(eng);
proj.Load(projectPath);

string res = proj.GetEvaluatedProperty(propertyName);

proj.SetProperty(propertyName, newValue);
proj.Save(projectPath);
```

This is more or less untested (it was actually to update the application revision), but I believe it should do what you need.  If it does, just compile it to a console app and call the exe from ou pre-build.

For completeness, here's the VB version:

```
Dim eng As New Engine()
Dim proj As New Project(eng)
proj.Load(projectPath)

Dim res As String = proj.GetEvaluatedProperty(propertyName)

proj.SetProperty(propertyName, newValue)
proj.Save(projectPath)
```

HTH